# C++ measure time between function call and callback

Tags: c++, function, callback, timestamp

I am working on an automated test framework for asynchronous applications. 
One of the aspects to abserve is the applications answering time behavior.
And I wonder if and how it would be possible to track the time between a function call, and the call of the corresponding event callback function.

Example:

I am setting the input gain of an audio input device

```
virtual void setGain(unsigned int gain) = 0;
```

This causes the underlaying library to perform some system calls, and the fire an event sooner or later

```
virtual void onGainChanged(IRtcAudioRecordingDevicePtr device, unsigned int gain) = 0;
```

The aim is now, to get the current time when setGain is calles, and when onGainChanged is called, to determine the timespan.

This should be done by an external component (e.g. a RuntimeObserver), as generic as possible.

Do you have any clues on how to design such a module?

Thank you in advance

Comment: is `setGain` and `onGainChanged` called on the same device? Also what is the targeted platform (IOS, Win32 , etc) ?

Comment: Yes, they are called on the same device, and it is ensured, that there cannot be two or more calls to setGain, if no onGainChanged has been received before. Target platform is Win32 as well as Mac OSX for the first step, mobile platforms are in focus, so it should be platform independent...

Comment: ok , one more question , are you using C++11 or c++98 ? Also what is the required timer precision (miliseconds /seconds) ?

Comment: We are using c++98 and it does not seem to be updated to 11 in short. milliseconds would be great, but it has not to be 1 ms precision...

Comment: ok, will write a reply shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is on the same platform it boils down to two parts for this system: 1:Time measurement and 2:Generic Implementation(more problematic)

**1 Time Measurement:**

The concept behind this is to measure the time when `setGain` and `onGainChanged` are called. The difference between those two time measurement will be equal to time delay you want to measure.

Here is some basic example using made up types and functions (will explain those later):

```
TimeValue s = GetNowTime();
setGain(...);

//after some computations:
TimeValue e = GetNowTime();
onGainChanged(...);
TimeDuration d = (e - s);
cout << "Lag:" << d;
```

On win32 platform `TimeValue` (and `TimeDuration`) can be `unsigned int` and `GetNowTime` can be [`timeGetTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx). The result of this will be in miliseconds.

If you are looking for a cross platform solution (in c++98) it would be best to choose a library such as [`boost::timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/timer/timer.htm) or [`boost::chrono`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/chrono.html) (you should investigate first and check the available solutions first).
Ideally, if you switch to c++ 11 you can use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (here `TimeValue` is `std::chrono::time_point` and `TimeDuration` is `std::chrono::duration`)

**2: Implementation**

There are a lot of ways you can implement this in a generic way and i don't think there is one perfect solution. One way i would do it is like this:

```
//some header
enum Events
{
    kGainEvent  
};

#ifdef USE_EVENT_TRACKING

    class EventTimeHandler
    {
    public:
        using Duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration;
        using TimePoint = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;

        static EventTimeHandler* Instance;
        EventTimeHandler();

        void TrackStartEvent(Events e);
        void TrackEndEvent(Events e);

    private:
        std::map<Events,TimePoint> m_times;
    };



    inline void TrackStartEvent(Events e)
    {
        EventTimeHandler::Instance->TrackStartEvent(e);
    }
    inline void TrackEndEvent(Events e)
    {
        EventTimeHandler::Instance->TrackEndEvent(e);
    }

#else

    inline void TrackStartEvent(Events e){}//empty implementaiton
    inline void TrackEndEvent(Events e){}//empty implementaiton

#endif

//cpp file:
EventTimeHandler::EventTimeHandler()
{
    Instance = this;
}
void EventTimeHandler::TrackStartEvent(Events e)
{
    m_times[e] = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
void EventTimeHandler::TrackEndEvent(Events e)
{
    TimePoint now_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Duration d = now_time - m_times[e];//should check here if m_times has key e for safety ?

    //print time in milseconds as double
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds<double>>(d).count();
}
```

Usage:

```
TrackStartEvent(kGainEvent);
setGain(...);

//after some computations:
TrackEndEvent(kGainEvent);
onGainChanged(...);

//code will do nothing if USE_EVENT_TRACKING is not defined. This will allow to turn the system on and off
```

I wrote the code out of my head , i hope i did not miss any errors.

Comment: This looks quite nice! I will give it a try during this week =) Thanks so far.